# How should I name this many-to-many table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

I have the following tables in my Ruby on Rails application:

- `stocks` with all the stock items
- `stock_suppliers` with all the stock suppliers. I cannot name it `suppliers` because I have other types of suppliers.

I have to create a many-to-many association from these two tables. How should I go about naming it?

I guess the logical name would be `stocks_stock_suppliers`, but I'm looking for something more readable.

Do you think `supplier_details` would be bad naming? My model would be called `SupplierDetail` instead of `StocksStockSupplier`, which is neater I think.

Comment: You can use `SupplierDetail` and i will suggest you to go for `has_many :through` instead of many to many

Comment: Refer this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks @DeepakMahakale. I have decided to go with `stocks_stock_suppliers` as table and then use `SupplierDetails` and `StockDetails` as aliases.